# AMAZing firefox failure to render page! like, at all

Tags: html, css, firefox

I'm not even sure where to start on this one.  in (some versions) of ff 3.6 (maybe others) my float-tastic page, doesn't render.  At all:  if you switch from another tab, the old page continues to show.  if you reload, it will draw /some/ elements over the other page (really!).  If you scroll, you get a page of ridiculous glitches and 5 to 30px high repeats.

Here is the offending page:
http://artdispenser.com/quarterrat/index2.php

It's set up as a long column with alternating floats to create a punk rock type look.  The page is randomly generated, so feel free to reload it a few times.

Seems to work well on other browsers.  Has anybody ever seen anything like this?  any idea where to begin?  I figure that this page is such an insane pile of fail that anybody who knows what is going on will immediately know the problem.

- Thanks, folks!

Comment: http://validator.w3.org/check?uri=http%3A%2F%2Fartdispenser.com%2Fquarterrat%2Findex2.php&charset=%28detect%20automatically%29&doctype=Inline&group=0

Comment: However, the *way* in which that pages breaks FF (3.6.13) is quite interesting and **is a bug**. The page background is not cleared and FF tries a "partial rendering" over the existing page content. *This rendering seems to be using incorrect buffers*. Switching to another tab and then back persists the view in "the other tab". Potential use for an exploit I imagine. (The issue isn't that the page isn't rendered "correctly" per developer intent so much as *the rendering pipeline itself is failing at a lower level*.)

Comment: @pst - Please describe the bug. How is it using incorrect buffers? The exploit comment is pure guesswork and does not apply.  From what I can tell, this is incorrectly served, invalid html and css. Garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @pst - what do you mean by "the background not being cleared".  you mean like a css clear:both?

Comment: @Trass Vasston & Rob Try it and see. I mean the *graphics buffers* are incorrect. The exploitation comment was that the rendering is wrong for what *is* -- the elements *exist* but are not rendered correctly (like an old game where textures are missing/incorrect/duplicated). It took me a minute to realize that I was *not* on SO after trying to load the link in FF (3.6.13) as it *looked* like SO (because it "wasn't cleared"): It shows X when Y is loaded (I have not put forth any mention of potential overflow as *that* would be guesswork ;-).

Comment: @Trass Vasston @Rob I am awful with graphics, but here is a screen-shot with some text: http://img202.imageshack.us/f/ffbuf.jpg/ This is only a very simple case of what happens. Normally it's just a bunch of (often repeating, "half drawn", and "jagged looking") image sections as though image buffers weren't be cleared and/or used correctly. The "previous page" sometimes, but not always, comes after the artifacts from mis-behaving page are not drawn on that region.

Comment: @Rob And it's a bug because well, just look at the image :-) What would you call a text editor where, a file is opened, and upon opening another file (with invalid data), loading the other files contents as best as it can, but *not* updating the editor display to reflect this? (Nor does it display an "critical failure" message or warning) The bug I am talking about is merely in the display issues and making FF behave in an *unstable (as far as rendering) fashion*.

Comment: @pst I don't know if it is an exploit or not but this is an old Firefox font rendering issue for monospace fonts. Using firebug if you change the font for `.byline` from `courier` to `courier new`, then it renders the page fine.

Comment: @pst - Just because it doesn't render correctly doesn't make it a bug but I don't have time to look further into this. Also, you still don't say what you mean by "graphics buffers" and how you are analyzing them.

Comment: @Rob -- the graphic buffers (where, uhm, graphics are drawn?) from the previous page are clearly *not* being cleared and otherwise lead to the other spectacular blt'ing problems (partial draws, overlapping repeats, etc). I don't know of a simpler way to say this. It is a bug *precisely because of this*. It doesn't matter what causes this is and no markup (as invalid as it may be, which is a problem in itself) should ever cause such an effect. As sarcastyx pointed out, changing to 'courier new' fixes the problem - although the bug-report seems distantly related at best in symptoms.

Comment: @pst - We don't call them graphics buffers in this context. No one has access to them and there's no way to view them. Only the final result. Those are programming terms developer's working with the program use.

Comment: @Rob My mistake then. It was the best way I knew of describing the issue observed. Thanks for being patient :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For starters you have the same id used multiple times on the page. That is bad, very bad HTML. However that is not the problem.

Secondly, [FF does have issues rendering monospace fonts](http://www.undermyhat.org/blog/2009/09/css-font-family-monospace-renders-inconsistently-in-firefox-and-chrome/). Which in your case would be `Courier`. Change that to `Courier New` and it will work again. But then you will have to resize the font accordingly.

I would highly recommend using web-safe fonts. A sample list of these fonts can be found on http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html or on http://www.ampsoft.net/webdesign-l/WindowsMacFonts.html.

And as @David Dorward mentioned, validate the page. That might have also picked your font rendering issue.

Answer (score 1):

This part at the end doesn't look very encouraging:

```
</body> 
</html>kes to move the world.You unlock this door with the key of imagination. Beyond it is another dimension: a dimension of sound, a dimension of sight, a dimension of mind. You're moving into a land of both shadow and substance, of things and ideas; you've just crossed over into the Twilight Zone.
    </div>-->
</div> 

</div> 

</body> 
</html>
```

It doesn't help that you never *opened* an `html` tag, even though you're closing it. Twice.

Comment: oh my, how embarrassing.  (I believe the html & body /was/ in fact opened, however)  That was fixed in my working version already, and the problem still persists.  I have updated the page.  try it now?

Comment: The start tag for `<body>` is optional in HTML.